# How to move cursor to next field auto without hit Tab Key in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Suppose I set MaxLength=3 for a textbox, when user input 3 char in this field, I want to the cursor move to next item.

It's default is user must hit Tab or use mouse to move the cursor to next field.

How to implement this request?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more clever way but at first glance I would say a simple way would be to you add a `TextChanged` event to your `TextBox` and then when the number of characters hits the 3 you mention then set the focus to what you want.

So if this is in your xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyText1" TextChanged="txtChanged"/>
<TextBox x:Name="MyText2" />
```

Then in your code something like:

```
private void txtChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyText1.Text.Length == 3)
    {
         MyText2.Focus()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If we use txtChangedEvent, then it make no sense to set MaxLength = "3". Any more simple solution? Maybe only set up some property in xaml?

Comment: @KentZhou: Keep MaxLength, what if a user pastes text in with Ctrl+V