# How to create a foolproof phone number field - and accounting for copy/paste

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to split my phone number fields into 3 fields (area code, next 3, next 4).  I want to account for a few conditions:

1. After the field has the specified number of digits, the cursor will automatically move to the next field.
2. If a user pastes their entire phone number in the first field, jQuery will distribute the 10 digits out accordingly.

I've gotten #1 to work, no problem: [How to move cursor to next field auto without hit Tab Key in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221872/how-to-move-cursor-to-next-field-auto-without-hit-tab-key-in-silverlight)

However, #2 is proving to be way out of my jQuery league - so I am requesting some help here.

Secondly, I'm wondering if I'm overlooking anything here?  I don't think so, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

I should add that I've considered this: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo - but I tend to think that the above is more pleasing to users...perhaps I am mistaken though.

**Update** - USA only phone numbers =).

**Update 2** - A friend sent me this: http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/

Comment: (area code, next 3, next 4) — My phone numbers consist of the area code and then 6 digits. Be liberal in what you accept.

Comment: You might also want to have it ignore all non-numeric key strokes, since the user, not knowing how this all will work, likely will enter parentheses, dashes and/or periods.

Comment: I'd keep it all in one text field. Three as you describe is going to be too rigid for the coming months. The rules are changing in the US, and also this format doesn't even begin to address international numbers.

Comment: @JonathanM:  Link to rule changes in the US, please?

Comment: @Quentin are you in the US?  I should say this is US only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this - take the field value, remove the non-numeric characters, test the length, and split it up if necessary:

```
$('#telephone1').on('change',function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        phone = $this.val().replace(/\D/g, ''); // remove non-numeric characters
    if (phone.length > 3) {
        $('#telephone3').val(phone.substr(6,4));
        $('#telephone2').val(phone.substr(3,3));
        $('#telephone1').val(phone.substr(0,3));
    } else {
        $('#telephone1').val(phone);
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6was/

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize this was to go inside the other.  10-4, thanks, I think it looks good then.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = $('.number').html();
var first = num.substr(0,3);
var second = num.substr(3,4);
var third = num.substr(7,4);
var newNum = first + ' ' + second + ' ' + third;
$('.number').html(newNum);
```

Comment: Better to participate on the newer questions than one that is old and has accepted answer already.  Sometimes tech changes or people have something really clever to add to an old question, but they probably knew about this sort of jQuery 2 years ago when this question was asked...